# Prevent d3 brush from having null selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js, brush

Having a selector with two handlers for selecting a range, I'm using d3.brush in order to get that range.

The problem that appears is when both selectors are on the same value (e.g. 0) the array containing the identical values [0, 0] becomes `null`.

I don't know why is this happening and how should it be avoided.

```
const brush = d3.brushX()
    .extent([[0, 0], [100, 100]])
    .on('brush.drag', () => {
        const selection = d3.event.selection;
        updateSomethingFromSelection(selection);
    })
    .on('end', () => {
        const selection = d3.event.selection;
        updateSomethingFromSelection(selection);
    })
    .on('brush.heatmap', () => {
        const selection  = d3.event.selection;
        updateSomethingElse(selection);
    });
```

What I want to avoid is having the selection null. Can you somehow tell d3 brush to never have null selection?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, if the range in the brush is 0 d3 will consider it ["empty"](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush/blob/master/src/brush.js#L113). As you can see [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush/blob/master/src/brush.js#L440) in the source, this will set the selection back to null. The only way to force d3 to draw on "empty" is by providing a very small value to d3 and having it draw that first.